Could you please help me with my MADDPG (Multi-Agent Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient Algorithm) implementation?
I am trying to implement MADDPG from scratch i finished the code but after 3000 episodes I still don't see any improvement on the behaviour of the agent could someone please help me. Thank you in advance ! Here is the code of my train function.
s : is the observation
a : is the action taken
ps : is the next observation
r : is the reward
d : is the state of the agents (True or False)

    s, a, r, ps, d = buffer.sample(MINI_BATCH)

    s = np.asarray(s)
    a = np.asarray(a)
    ps = np.asarray(ps)
    # we store the observation of the mini_batch in a dict this way it is easier to compute the target actor 
    # since the target actor only depends on it's associated observation and not the observation of other agent
    ps_by_agent = defaultdict(list)
    r_by_agent = defaultdict(list)
    s_by_agent = defaultdict(list)
    a_by_agent = defaultdict(list)
    d_by_agent = defaultdict(list)

    for i in range(MINI_BATCH):
        for j in range(len(agents)):
            ps_by_agent[str(j)].append(ps[i][j])
            r_by_agent[str(j)].append(r[i][j])
            s_by_agent[str(j)].append(s[i][j])
            a_by_agent[str(j)].append(a[i][j])
            d_by_agent[str(j)].append(d[i][j])

    if DEBUG:
        print('aaa', np.asarray(ps_by_agent['0']).shape)
        print('b', np.asarray(r_by_agent['0']).shape)
        print('c', np.asarray(s_by_agent['0']).shape)
        print('d', np.asarray(a_by_agent['0']).shape)
        print('e', np.asarray(d_by_agent['0']).shape)
    
    for i in range(len(agents)):
        target_action = []
        for k, agent in enumerate(agents):
            ps_ = torch.tensor(np.asarray(ps_by_agent[str(k)]),dtype=torch.float).to(device)
            target_action.append(agent.target_actor.forward(ps_))
        
        #ps_ = torch.tensor(ps_by_agent[str(i)]).to(device)
        ta_ = np.asarray([t.detach().cpu().numpy() for t in target_action])

        if DEBUG:
            print(ta_.shape)
            #print(ps_.shape)
            print(torch.tensor(ps).shape)
 
        tc = agents[i].target_critic.forward(
            torch.tensor(ps,dtype=torch.float).to(device),
            torch.reshape(torch.tensor(ta_,dtype=torch.float).to(device),(ps.shape[0],ps.shape[1],ACTION_SHAPE))
            )
        r_i = torch.tensor(r_by_agent[str(i)]).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).to(device)

        if DEBUG :
            print("r: ",r_i.shape)
            print("tc : ",tc.shape)

        # compute y_j the target we manipute the tensor to make sure they are the same dimension so they can add up 
        y_j = r_i+ gamma * tc

        if DEBUG:
            print(y_j.shape)
            print("state: ",torch.tensor(np.asarray(s)).shape)
            print("action : ",torch.tensor(np.asarray(a)).shape)


        q_i = agents[i].critic.forward(torch.tensor(s,dtype=torch.float).to(device),torch.tensor(a,dtype=torch.float).to(device))

        # compute the gradient for the critic
        critic_loss = F.mse_loss(y_j.to(device), q_i.to(device))
        agents[i].critic.optimizer.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward()
        agents[i].critic.optimizer.step()

        # compute the gradient for the actor
        action = []
        for k, agent in enumerate(agents):
            s_ = torch.tensor(np.asarray(s_by_agent[str(k)]),dtype=torch.float).to(device)
            action.append(agent.actor.forward(s_))
        
        a_ = np.asarray([t.detach().cpu().numpy() for t in action])
        c = agents[i].critic.forward(
            torch.tensor(s,dtype=torch.float).to(device),
            torch.reshape(torch.tensor(a_,dtype=torch.float).to(device),(s.shape[0],s.shape[1],ACTION_SHAPE))
            )
        actor_loss = -torch.mean(c)
        agents[i].actor.optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        agents[i].actor.optimizer.step()
        
    # soft upadate of the target critic and target actor
    # Update the target networks for each agent
    for i in range(len(agents)):
        for target_param, source_param in zip(agents[i].target_actor.parameters(), agents[i].actor.parameters()):
            target_param.data.copy_(TAU * source_param.data + (1.0 - TAU) * target_param.data)
        for target_param, source_param in zip(agents[i].target_critic.parameters(), agents[i].critic.parameters()):
            target_param.data.copy_(TAU * source_param.data + (1.0 - TAU) * target_param.data)

